# jasmine beforeEach and angular TestBed.configureTestingModule, sync or not?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a simple test with a simple config:

```
fdescribe("A spec", function() {
    let service: UserService;

    beforeEach(()=>{
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [UserService] });
    });

    it('should use UserService', () => {
        service = TestBed.get(UserService);
        expect(service.getValue()).toBe('real value');
    });
});
```

It works fine, but if I just want to remove the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` outside of `beforeEach`

```
fdescribe("A spec", function() {
    let service: UserService;

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [UserService] });

    it('should use UserService', () => {
        service = TestBed.get(UserService);
        expect(service.getValue()).toBe('real value');
    });
});
```

it will throw an error:

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for UserService
```

That's because **TestBed** will not find any service under **UserService** because the configuration is not ready yet.

So, as you can see I've used **beforeEach** as a *sync* operation and I guess **TestBed.configureTestingModule** it's not *sync*.

What I am missing? How does **beforeEach** works without having to provide `async`, or `done()` options?

Or the problem itself its within **TestBed.configureTestingModule**?

I'm not sure how these two works toghether.

Can someone explain?

Comment: why do you want to remove the TestBed.configureTestingModule outside of beforeEach? Is there any reason? I think the dynamically generated module (aka testBed) dont exists globally outside of "it" / "beforeEach" statements. So if you don't call configureTestingModule you will have to provided service. I dont think you can have a work around for that

Comment: It does exists even outside of describe. I just wanted to know why do I  need to call beforeEach every time, even for one single test, instead of just writing my configuration without it

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `TestBed.configureTestingModule` needs to be called on every `it` statement. Otherwise the configuration will reset every time. That's why we need to call it within `beforeEach`, although the logic seems stupid for me.